# String comparison in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a table that has some course labels such as

```
Subject | Course | 
ACC     | 201
ACC     | 843
ACC     | 843I
ACC     | 850
ACC     | 930
```

I'm using this SQL to get ACC 843, ACC 843I and ACC850:

```
select Subj_Code, crse_code
        from section_info
        Where (crse_code between '800' and '899') and subj_code = 'ACC'
        order by crse_code
```

But somehow, this misses the 843I.  How can I get this check to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Will the course name always be 3 digits at start followed by whatever?

Comment: Is BETWEEN supposed to work with text?!

Comment: @Crono Yes, I believe it is. It will perform a lexicographic comparison

Comment: The between actually works.

Comment: I do believe it is always three characters, but you never know when someone will try to sneak in four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Subj_Code, crse_code
        from section_info
        Where (cast(left(crse_code,3) as int) as num between 800 and 899) and subj_code = 'ACC'
        order by crse_code
```

Hope this works, try it out and let me know. Thanks!

Comment: I thought of this as I was leaving work on Friday (ain't that always the way?).  I shall give this a try and let you know.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson : can you accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that course name has a fixed format of 3 digits followed by an optional letter, you could simply compare on the first 3 characters of the column. Additionally, since the first 3 characters are always digits, you may want to convert them to numbers before comparing. Your query will then become something like this:

```
select Subj_Code, crse_code
from section_info
Where (cast(left(crse_code,3) as int) between 800 and 899) and subj_code = 'ACC'
order by crse_code
```

Comment: numbers are not compared with strings here

Comment: Lol! you and me have the same idea.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm sure there's another way to do it that someone will post.

Comment: I really wouldn't do this, as it's not gonna take advantage of any indexes.

Comment: I see. However, I assumed while answering that there are no indexes on the specified column. On a side note, is it recommended to index text columns?

Comment: Alright, thanks for the info. Just that I haven't come across it anywhere in the DB at work, and figured there might be special considerations for text types as opposed to others.

Comment: Both you and developer got it.  I wish I had thought of it before I posted instead of when I got in my car to leave work.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WHERE crse_code LIKE '8%'
```

Comment: Just to satisfy my own curiosity: what SIS is this?

Comment: I like this answer! Sometimes it is the simple solutions that escape us.

Comment: So long as there's no Course 8000.  Ever.

Comment: I thought of using left just as I was getting in my car to go home after I posted this, but the Like could work too.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Orderedcourses AS
(
    SELECT Subj_Code, crse_code,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cast(left(crse_code,3) as int) )AS RowNumber
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader 
) 
SELECT Subj_Code, crse_code, RowNumber  
FROM Orderedcourses
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN '800' and '899';
```

This is A Common Table Expression which i have created to store the rownumber for sorting the column on course numbers and it is called by the query down there to get the ordered results of the column.